# How to close Response object when we get http body directly in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

When we write REST client with jersey we should close `Response` like this:

```
Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();

Response r = null;
try {
    r = c.target("http://localhost:8080/testrest/customers/854878").request().get();
    Customer cus = r.readEntity(Customer.class);

    /* process result */
} catch (Exception e) {
    /* log here */
    if (r != null) {
        r.close();
    }
}
```

how should we access `Response` object when we directly read HTTP body:

```
Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Customer cus = c.target("http://localhost:8080/testrest/customers/854878").request().get(Customer.class);
/* close Response object and process result */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Glassfish's `jersey-client` implementation version 2.3.1 ([or check the other versions too](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.3.1/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.java#JerseyInvocation.Builder)), you can follow the calls that [`get(Class)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.3.1/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.java#JerseyInvocation.Builder.get%28java.lang.Class%29) makes. A little down the line you [will find a call to](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.3.1/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/InboundMessageContext.java#InboundMessageContext.readEntity%28java.lang.Class,java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.annotation.Annotation%5B%5D,org.glassfish.jersey.internal.PropertiesDelegate%29)

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext#readEntity(Class<T>, Type, Annotation[], PropertiesDelegate)
```

which, based on some rules, closes the response

```
if (!buffered && !(t instanceof Closeable) && !(t instanceof Source)) {
    entityContent.close(); // wrapper to the actual response stream
}
```

where `t` is the object created based on the specified `Class` object.

The API itself doesn't seem to say anything about this so an implementation doesn't have to close the underlying response stream. The only thing I could find is from `Client` javadoc which states

> Client instances must be properly closed before being disposed to
>   avoid leaking resources.

So do not depend on a specific implementation, make sure to close everything yourself, even if that means you have to break your Fluent method invocations and store intermediate object references in variables.

Answer (score 0):

Client has a close method. Look into its sources. If Client.close doesn't clean up its resources then you must obtain a reference to Response and close it. Otherwise you'll have hanging connections.
If code allows you to do something, it doesn't mean you should. But from your questions I gather that you understand it.